# Split a huge file at locations where consecutive lines don't have the same first field

Tags: sed, awk, split, large-files, text-processing

I have a huge sorted text file (10 million lines). I want to split it into small files of size about 10,000 each. But there shouldn't be any file whose last line has the same first field as that of first line of any other file. In other words, the split points should be near 10k'th line, but so that the line before split should have a different first field than the line after.

I thought of a tedious way. In another file, somehow print all possible split locations where lineN and lineN+1 have different first field. Then write program to select only those split points that are near 10k. But now I can't use the `split` command as it only allows fixed lines per splitted file.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, untested, should do it:

```
awk '
nr == 10000 { got10k = 1 }
got10k && ($1 != prev) { nr = 0 }
++nr == 1 { fileName = "outfile" ++numFiles; got10k = 0 }
{ print > fileName; prev = $1 }
' file
```

Comment: Actually, I meant something same. Somehow had an image of `for` loop since it actually works the same way. :)

Comment: It's fine to imagine a `for` (or `while` or `until` or whatever construct you like) loop that's built into awk, you just wouldn't then go and write your own redundant loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `awk` command to write a small script to write data to different files.

Using the `awk` `for` loop, you can check if the two fields match with the previous line's fields then continue writing to the same file (after reading/ writing 10k lines), else write to a new file.

Comment: No, you would never write a `for` loop in awk to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanatoon?

Comment: awk processes each record in a file one at a time so what would you use a `for` loop for? Try writing the code and you'll see what I mean.